# populate actors and director at the same level in sub nested array with aggregate ERROR: Does not populate them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I want to populate all actors and director using mongoose aggregation function. This is my model.

```
             const tvShowSchema = new Schema({

               name: String,

               year: Number,

               country: String,

                       seasons: [{

                          number: Number,

                          year: Number,

                               episodes:[{
                                     title: String,

                                     number: Number,

                                     releasedOn: Date,

                                     description: String,
 
                               cast:[
                                  {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                                    ref:'actors'
                                      }],

                                    director:{
                                      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                                      ref:'directors'
                                       }

                                        },

                               {timeStamps: true
                                    }

                                      ]

                                 }]

                             });
```

I'm using lookup as function to populate actors and director. This is my method in tv show controller:

```
                  export const getTvShowEpisode = async(req,res) =>{

                                    try{

                             const { tvShowId } = req.params;

                             const { seasonId } = req.params;

                             const { episodeId } = req.params;

                            const tvShowEpisode = await TVShow.aggregate([



                               {"$unwind": "$seasons"},

                                {"$unwind": "$seasons.episodes"},
          
                                 {"$match":{

                                 "_id": Types.ObjectId(tvShowId),
                                "seasons._id": Types.ObjectId(seasonId),
                                "seasons.episodes._id": Types.ObjectId(episodeId)

                                       }},

                         //WHY don't populate actors and director

                               {"$lookup": {"from":'actors', "localField": 'seasons.episodes.cast', 
                            "foreignField": '_id', "as": 'actors'}
                               }, 
        
                           {"$lookup": {"from":'directors', "localField": 
                  'seasons.episodes.director', "foreignField": '_id', "as": 'director'}},

                                   {"$project": {
                                  "_id": Types.ObjectId(tvShowId),
                                   "seasons._id": Types.ObjectId(seasonId),
                                  "seasonsNumber": "$seasons.number",
                                "seasonsYear": "$seasons.year",
                              "episode": "$seasons.episodes"}},

                              ]);


                              if (tvShowEpisode) {
                                  res.send(tvShowEpisode);
                                   } else {
                                          res
                                       .status(404)
                             .send({ mensaje: `tv show episode not found` });
                               }
                      }
                            catch(error){
                               console.log(error);
                                res.status(500).send({message: `error: \n\n${error}`});
                                    }

                                 };
```

I don't know if the order I set up the pipelines operator is wrong. I'm using project pipeline to select the fields I want. I should see all information about actors and director from specific show tv episode, but I only watch the ids.

How could I do to watch all actors and director included in specific tv show episode and not the ids only?

This is the actual output:

```
             [
                     {
                         "seasons": {
                          "_id": "6007609a9cc33a148436060d"
                             },
                          "_id": "60075d219cc33a14843605fe",
                            "seasonsNumber": 1,
                            "seasonsYear": 2010,
                                 "episode": {
                                     "cast": [
                                        "6004b348b1cd7f28c8d5569d",
                                        "6004b4323265a91b18f96d39",
                                         "6004b4423265a91b18f96d3a"
                                            ],
                                      "_id": "6007609a9cc33a1484360610",
                                      "title": "resilence",
                                       "number": 3,
                                "releasedOn": "2009-08-19T19:00:00.000Z",
                            "description": "learning from negative aspects",
                              "director": "600759119cc33a14843605fc"
                                 }
                                  }
                                  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved now.

I had to delete lines of code from $project pipeline and works.